# Quick Datasheet Interpretation - TI LM1084

Tags: power, ldo, linear-regulator

Was wondering if someone could give [this datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwig8fjKrsPKAhUS92MKHZxVDjMQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fds%2Fsymlink%2Flm1084.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH_j5pQ96JTLc4-bGHgM2UASMijSA&sig2=ba9E0a5VzLi5VbqBySf-zg) a look over in regards to the max current it can source out.

It's rated at 5A out, but it says under "Current Limit" for LM1084-5.0 at Vin=10V that the TYP current limit is 8A.

I'm putting 12V at 6A into the LDO. Do you think it's safe to draw 5V at 6A from the LM1084-5.0 LDO?

Comment: 7V*6A = 42W. That smells like fire. Have you considered a buck regulator? Or some other source of 5V?

Answer (score 2):

The device is rated at 5A. It has a current limit (for fault protection) with a typical value of 8A and minimum 5.5 (a little over its rated current). The device will then be thermally limited, so you need to provide heat sinking for the power that it dissipates. Power * Rth j-a gives the die temperature rise above ambient. Rth j-a = Rth j-a (die to case) + Rth c-a (case to ambient). As @uint128_t pointed out you power level is very high. The device will overheat in practical situations with your application.

Answer (score 0):

The typical Ilimit appears to be based on the power dissipation, suggesting 8A is possible with 5v across the LDO.

With your higher input voltage, at 6A you would be dissipating more than the datasheet uses for the typical 8A data point. So no, on the first count.

The datasheet gives a guarranteed minimum Ilimit of 5.5A, for any dissipation conditions, so a higher typical limit is not guarranteed. No on the second count.

But try it, with plenty of heatsinking, it's close, and you may have picked a good one. If one works, don't expect another one to.